# Xcode 12 Getting Errors

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, xcode12

I am using Xcode for creating a watchOS app with iOS application. When I run my empty application, I am getting the errors below in debug console. I'm not sure why I am getting these errors. [image]

```
WatchApp Extension[1722:69488] [default] lookupMainFuncAddressInMachHeader:71: Invalid Swift entry point data
WatchApp Extension[1722:69488] [default] lookupMainFuncAddressInMachHeader:77: Swift entry point address could not be determined.
```

Comment: I am not sure why this question is downvoted. I feel that other people are also experiencing the same issue for Xcode 12

Answer (score 1):

There is an ongoing discussion on the Apple developer forum: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/661727

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by setting the watchOS deployment target to 6.0 and downloading and installing v6.2 of the simulator.